# What's the policy on answering a question where the correct answer is simply "yes"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, allowed-questions

Occasionally I see questions on math.SE where either the answer is completely trivial -- for example [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1291280/inverse-of-two-matrices-multiplied) where the correct answer would just be "Yes.  You did it correctly" -- or questions where a few questions/responses from people in the comments is enough to answer the question for the OP.  Either way an answer just seems to be overkill.

What is the policy with these types of questions?

My $\$0.02$: I can't see most of the questions of these types being helpful to anyone, thus I would think that they should be closed.  But none of the closure reasons seem to fit.  Perhaps we could make a new one?

Comment: If none of closure reasons fit, you can [make a new one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1291280/inverse-of-two-matrices-multiplied#comment2629360_1291280).

Comment: [This meta question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/20097/how-to-answer-proof-verification-questions) asks basically the same thing, and has (in my opinion) a very good answer. I recall other times this has come up on meta, though I can't find them.

Comment: @Meelo I think you can find most of posts discussing this when you browse ([meta-tag:solution-verification]) tag here on meta. (Which is, of course, different from the ([tag:solution-verification]) tag on the main site, although they share the same name.)

Answer (score 23):

Sometimes a "yes" or a "yes you did it right" is all that's necessary; my own question history has a few of these. But many of the questions that tend to be answerable with "yes" are relatively simple questions, and it is my broad belief that these users could benefit from some additional insight that could relate to the question.

Personally, if I find that a question is overly technical and just needs a "yes, you did it right" answer, I post that as an answer and mark it as Community Wiki so as not to leave the impression that I'm lazily rep-hunting.